# ASP.NET MVC 4 currency field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I get an error ("The field Amount must be a number") on my web page on a currency field. It is because of the dollar sign ($50.00).

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
```

What else do I need to do if I want to keep the dollar sign?

Comment: it may depend which is current culture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default MVC model binder [cannot parse value formatted for display](http://books.google.by/books?id=B2hWImXICj8C&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=applyformatineditmode%20currency&source=bl&ots=_H34w7Un2e&sig=kijCb5RM7n_kzFf4RCshSWtWKMk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yv3-UKLxBKSD4ATM5IC4Dw&ved=0CGsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). So, you should write your own model binder and register it for this type (suppose type name is Foo):

```
public class FooModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Amount");

        if (result != null)
        {
            decimal amount;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(result.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out amount))                
                return new Foo { Amount = amount };                                

            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Wrong amount format");                
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Add this binder for Foo type at Application_Start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Foo), new FooModelBinder());
```

Ah, and last thing - remove `data-val-number` attribute from amount textbox (otherwise you will continue seeing message that it's not a number):

```
$("#Amount").removeAttr("data-val-number");
```

Now you will get validation error message if input value will not be correct currency amount (e.g. `$10F.0`).

---

BTW I think it's better to use `ApplyFormatInEditMode = false` than implement all this stuff to help MVC bind your custom formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set edit mode to false. Then it will only show the decimal value while text will be formatted.

```
ApplyFormatInEditMode = false
```