# Model throwing validation error for currency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to format my values to show in a format such as
x,xxx.00 / xxx,xxx.00. I have used

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.cash) } })
```

which gives a value of $x,xxx.00.

However the problem is, if I enter 123456 it saves and when I reopen the form to edit cash is $1,234,56.00 as I would expect, However upon saving,  it throws the error that `$1,234,56.00 is invalid for cash` . Null is being passed to the controller, so there is no way I can replace the '$'and ',' to get it to save if those are causing the issue.

My Question is, how or what is missing to get my currency format to save without throwing this validation error.

Model

```
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,0}")]
    public Nullable<decimal> cash{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403803/asp-net-mvc-4-currency-field & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093392/asp-net-mvc-validation-annotation-for-dollar-currency. You can write custom model binder includes `decimal.TryParse` to handle the format or use `ApplyFormatInEditMode = false` on `DisplayFormatAttribute`.

Comment: Yes its invalid because a value of `$1,234,56.00` cannot be parsed to a decimal. You would need a custom `ModelBinder` to make binding work. (and **never** set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods - instead apply a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute